# Data attribute format not working using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
alert($("#bottomTbodyTable tr [data-testlog]").length); // display value 0
alert($("#bottomTbodyTable tr").data("testlog")); // display the correct value
```

I can't understand the value 0 when there is clearly value during the display of this attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted

```
$("#bottomTbodyTable tr[data-testlog]").length
```

That is the same with no space between `tr` and `[data-testlog]`, a space meaning the element having the data attribute would have been a descendant of the `tr`.

Comment: really, no space is needed.... I'll give it a try.. this really helps if it works.